# Android: Get number of files in zip (with Storage Volume/Storage Access Framework)

Tags: java, android, zip, android-7.0-nougat, storage-access-framework

I'm using the Storage Volume to unzip a zip file on the SD card of my Android 7.0 phone to a folder on the SD card:

```
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(myZipFile.getUri());
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(bis);
ZipEntry zipEntry;

while ((zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) { ... }
```

To show the progress in a dialog I need the total amount of elements in the zip file. How do you do this with the Storage Volume/StorageAccesFramework?

You can't do it this way because you don't get the actual paths with SV/SAF:

```
ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(pathToZipFile);
int size = zip.size();
```

... and iterating over the whole file to count the number of files before you iterate over it again to unzip the file is slow:

```
while ((zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
    size++;
}
```

Comment: @ElhoussineZennati I think you posted the wrong link. Not only does nobody say anything about the amount of files in the zip file but it's also about direct access to the asset folder and the SD card (2012, so probably Android 4), not SV/SAV, which handle stuff in a completely different way.

Comment: my bad , deleted it

Comment: There is nothing in your post concerning Storage Volumes or Storage Access Framework.

Comment: Please show how you obtain myZipFile  and tell the value of myZipFile.getUri().toString().

Comment: @greenapps I used `createAccessIntent` with `null` (Storage Volume) to get access to the whole SD card, then traversed the tree with `myfolder.find("mysubfolder")` until I got the zip file as a `DocumentFile` ([click](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/StorageVolume)).  `myZipFile.getUri().toString()` gives me `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/xxxx-xxxx%3A/document/xxxx-xxxx%3AmyFolder%2FmyZipFile.zip` ("xxxx-xxxx" is the number of the SD card). I know how to get the file and unzip it but I don't know how to get the number of files inside the zip.